# Is it possible to have a sound notification on the smartwatch the is sent by phone?

Tags: android, audio, notifications, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm developing a smartwatch application that will be integrated with android phone using sony3 smartwatch
but is it possible to have the notification on the smartwatch but not the default sound, I need to have a notification sound from my application

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sony Smartwatch 3 has no built in speaker.